# Problems Applying MATLAB Filters to Dicom Images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, dicom, edge-detection

I am working with dicom chest PA's. I have no problem loading the images and doing basic thresholding work, however I need to apply some filters. I will be designing my own filters in the future but for now I want to use the MATLAB ones. The images are 16bit and in MATLAB docs it says that `fspecial` works fine with 16bit images.

When I try using `fspecial` or the `edge` functions i get similar results to the images as shown below.

**My question: why is this happening and how do i fix it?**

Your help is appreciated.
Regards,

```
full_path = 'I:\Find and Treat\Anonymized_Data\000026_20050607112512_1.dcm';
dicominfo_image = dicominfo(full_path);
dicomread_image = dicomread(dicominfo_image);
dicomread_image = mat2gray(dicomread_image);
c = imcomplement(dicomread_image);

figure,
subplot(1,3,1)
imshow(c)
f = fspecial('laplacian');
cf = filter2(f,c);
subplot(1,3,2)
imshow(cf)
f1 = fspecial('log');
cf1 = filter2(f1,c);
subplot(1,3,3)
imshow(cf1)
```

[image: results]

**EDIT**

I added and modified the following code to take into account the dynamic range and plotted a mesh plot i obtained the following result and error message.

> Warning: Error updating LineStrip.
>
> Update failed for unknown reason
>
> Warning: Error updating LineStrip.
>
> Update failed for unknown reason

```
figure,
subplot(2,3,1)
imshow(c, [])
f=fspecial('laplacian');
cf=filter2(f,c);
subplot(2,3,2)
imshow(cf, [])
f1=fspecial('log');
cf1=filter2(f1,c);
subplot(2,3,3)
imshow(cf1, [])

subplot(2,3,4)
mesh(c)
subplot(2,3,5)
mesh(cf)
subplot(2,3,6)
mesh(cf1)
```

[image: updated image]

**EDIT**

[LINK TO IMAGE FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y235nai1sxwrqss/1_1.dcm?dl=0)

Comment: Did you tried to overwrite the dynamic range to min/max `imshow(cf1, [])` ?

Comment: I suggest, you visualize an image with mesh(image) and take a look at the result. If this is wrong, the problems come from `filter`. If the mesh output looks ok, then you should look at your vizualisation.

Comment: i have update the question to take both the above suggestions into account, it hasn't helped much..

Comment: Have you tried changing the values for the filters? It totally looks like your image has just not enough contrast to make those filters work. Can you post the original image?

Comment: sorry for the slow reply @AnderBiguri i was awaiting permission from the hospital to upload the file, i have uploaded a different one they said i was allowed to use since it's already available online.. i get the same problem with it...

Comment: I would always avoid running matlab function on non-double data.

Comment: the image data used in the filters is double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your images are just *too big*.

The Laplacian operator is a 3x3 matrix that approximates the second derivative of the images. Your image is 2700x2200 which means that the variability of the pixels in that small size(comparing to the whole image) is neglectable. You can see it better if you plot your Laplacian filter image as `imshow(cf(300:end-300,300:end-300), [])` removing the boundaries (where you actually have a big gap). To solve this you'll need to or redefine a Laplacian filter with a higher dimension or resize the image you have to a lower size (`imresize` is your friend).

The same happens with the `log` filter, but in this case you can do something about it. The default log filter returned by `fspecial` is 5x5, but you can actually ask `fspecial` to create bigger filters.

If you call it the following way:

```
f1=fspecial('log',50,0.3);
cf1=filter2(f1,c);
imshow(cf1, [])
```

You get the next figure, that looks kind of a good log filter result.

[image]

Comment: Can't say anything more than +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! It was relatively easy to see once the huge image was posted!